# Binomial Function and the hypergeometric function

Tags: probability, binomial-coefficients, hypergeometric-function

So lets define: $$h(r|M,N,n) = \frac{\binom{M}{r} \binom{N-M}{n-r}}{N \choose n}$$

Having the usual $\Gamma$ function we define the hypergeometric function:
$$F(a,b,c;t) = \sum_{r=0}^{\infty}\frac{\Gamma(a+r)\Gamma(b+r)\Gamma(c)}{\Gamma(a)\Gamma(b)\Gamma(c+r)}\frac{t^r}{r!}$$
And the generating function:
$$G(t) = \sum_{r=0}^{n}h(r|M,N,n)t^r$$
Proof that
$$G(t) = \frac{F(-M,-n,N-M-n+1;t)}{F(-M,-n,N-M-n+1;1)}$$

Comment: Perhaps this may help: http://www.milefoot.com/math/stat/pdfd-hypergeometric.htm

Answer (score 2):

You should express $h(r|M, N, n)$ and the hypergeometric functions in terms of [Pochhammer symbol](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PochhammerSymbol.html). To do so, you need the following properties :
$$\binom mn = \frac{m!}{n! (m-n)!}$$
$$ m! = (1)_m$$
$$ (m)_{n+k} = (m)_n  (m+n)_k$$
$$(m)_{-k} = \frac{(-1)^k}{(1-m)_k}$$

Using these properties, $h(r|M, N, n)$ becomes :

$$h(r|M, N, n) = \frac{(N-M)!(N-n)!}{N! (N-M-n)!}\,\frac{(-M)_r (-n)_r}{r! (N-M-n+1)_r}$$

Then

\begin{eqnarray}
G(t) &=& \frac{(N-M)!(N-n)!}{N! (N-M-n)!}\,\sum_{r=0}^n \frac{(-M)_r (-n)_r}{r! (N-M-n+1)_r} t^r \\ &=& \frac{(N-M)!(N-n)!}{N! (N-M-n)!}\, F(-M, -n, N-M-n+1;t)
\end{eqnarray}

Using [Chu-Vandermonde identity](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Chu-VandermondeIdentity.html), you can demonstrate that
$$F(-M, -n, N-M-n+1;t) = \frac{N! (N-M-n)!}{(N-M)!(N-n)!}$$

which gives you the desired result.